# Fill a dataframe with the output of a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to concatenate the output of a loop into dataframe.
This example is totally unrealistic, but just to try to demonstrate my problem, my error and the result I need.

```
for a in range(1,4):

    list1 = ["22", "23", "24", "25"]
    list2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
    
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Num': list1,'Alpha': list2})

    print(df)
```

My output:

[image]

Good output

```
   Num Alpha
0  22     a
1  23     b
2  24     c
3  25     d
4  22     a
5  23     b
6  24     c
7  25     d
8  22     a
9  23     b
10 24     c
11 25     d
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
l = []
for a in range(1, 4):
    
    list1 = ["22", "23", "24", "25"]
    list2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
    l.append(pd.DataFrame({'Num': list1, 'Alpha': list2}))
out = pd.concat(l,ignore_index = True)
```

Answer (score 4):

This is one way to do it using your code above. Create an empty list before your for loop and append the df to it. Then concat the final list.

```
l = []   

for a in range(1,4):
    list1 = ["22", "23", "24", "25"]
    list2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
    
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Num': list1,'Alpha': list2})

    l.append(df)

df = pd.concat(l)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `pd.concat` with `*3` instead of looping through a range of 3:

```
import pandas as pd
list1 = ["22", "23", "24", "25"]
list2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'Num': list1,'Alpha': list2})] * 3).reset_index(drop=True)
df
Out[1]: 
   Num Alpha
0   22     a
1   23     b
2   24     c
3   25     d
4   22     a
5   23     b
6   24     c
7   25     d
8   22     a
9   23     b
10  24     c
11  25     d
```

Comment: Interesting. I understand the first two solutions, but I'm not sure I understand this one. What is the '* 3' for? What is the purpose for this logic?

Comment: @ASH Instead of looping through a range of length 3, you are creating a list of 3 dataframes simply by multiplying and then concatenating the dataframes into one.